# existence of a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

let the G group of order 12. show that G has normal subgroup of order 3 or 4.

by showing G is not basic group, G has normal groups besides e and G. I know it is simple but I dont know what to do next..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the [Sylow Theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) and try to argue that $n_2=1$ or $n_3=1$.